# modelsim error vsim-3421 when run from xilinx ISE 14.2

Tags: modelsim

I designed and tested my VHDL code. I used ISIM (xilinx simulator) to test the code. ISIM was buggy so i switched to modelsim SE 10c.
when i run modelsim through xilinx ise i get following error in modelsim

**Fatal: (vsim-3421) Value -14 is out of range -7 to 7.**

my related VHDL code is

library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

library UNISIM;

use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

signal img_int                : integer range -7 to 7 ;

signal add1                   : integer range -7 to 7 ;

signal add2                   : integer range -7 to 7 ;

process (clk)

begin

```
if rising_edge(clk) then

    add1 <= to_integer( signed(e(0)) ) + to_integer( signed(e(1)) ) + 

            to_integer( signed(e(2)) ) + to_integer( signed(e(3)) );


    add2 <= to_integer( signed(e(4)) ) + to_integer( signed(e(5)) ) +

            to_integer( signed(e(6)) ) + to_integer( signed(e(7)) );

end if;
```

end process;

img_int <= add1 + add2;

**the problem line is**

img_int <= add1 + add2;

Can any tell why modelsim is giving this error?

Answer (score 0):

Because the minimum possible value of 'add1' is -7.  The same for 'add2'.
Adding 'add1' with 'add2' gives you a minimum value of -14.
That value (-14) can not be held in your 'img_int' signal.

You can extend the range of 'img_int' to e.g. integer range -14 to 14 or truncate the result.

Anyway:  Try to use the 'signed' and 'unsigned' types of the liberary 'ieee.numeric_std' i.s.o. the type 'integer'.